# Allocating an array of C++ objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object, constructor, allocation

I want to allocate an array of C++ objects using the following code:

```
class myClass {
public:
    myClass(int userValue)
    : value(userValue)
    { }
}

private:
    int value;
};

int main(){
    myClass* objArray = new myClass(22)[5];

    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
In constructor ‘myClass::myClass(int32)’:
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘[’ token
         objArray = new objArray(22)[5];
```

How should I create an array of objects then while passing parameters to them?

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<myClass> objArray(5, 22);
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you tell me the reason why it is not possible to allocate the objects array in regular way?